# code.ros.org/svn/ down?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need several files from there, is there an alternative?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/215392/code.ros.org/svn/-down?/) by [maxlklaxl](https://answers.ros.org/users/23486/maxlklaxl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-08-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like code.ros.org has gone down and likely won't be coming back up:

- http://lists.ros.org/pipermail/ros-users/2013-September/067953.html
- https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/issues/9102

---

Originally posted by [AndrewStraw](https://answers.ros.org/users/203/andrewstraw/) with karma: 171 on 2015-08-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0